# code for disabling check box after being chosen

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to php. My situation is after a user has chosen a check box,the check box will be disabled. The problem here is I'm not sure whether to use JavaScript or php,cause I know the code for JavaScript...but if I use JavaScript,how to store it in the database using php? Help will be appreciated.

php code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['Next']))
{   
    foreach($_POST['boxs'] as $f => $value){
        $sql = "UPDATE box SET status = '0' WHERE boxid = '$f'";
        mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    }

}
```

this is my code for php, but it will not update the database when it is executed. So, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Why would you want to save the fact that the check box is closed in the database after you have already got your data?

Comment: So that other user cannot choose the same check box

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('yourpage.php',{database_value:$("#checkbox").is(':checked')},function(data){
 // Data returned form php page
 $('#checkbox').attr("disabled",true); // Your checkbox id may anything you have given.
});
```

//PHP code yourpage.php
- First write code to update your database value from where the checkbox value is updated to the database.
- Then again return a value as you have given i.e. if checkbox value is updated as 1 then return as follows:

```
die('1');
```

or as your value is returned from the database

Comment: i have put my php code above...but it does not update the database.How?

Comment: now the database is updated, but the checkbox is not disabled

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the checkbox happens on users side. You cannot directly disable it after the user has klicked it with php. You need javascript for that.
To send the result to your backend use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the checkbox either in database driven code or using your javascript code. If your values are fetching from the database then as per condition you can disable the checkbox using AJAX request as :
- First update the record using AJAX request and when you get data as result then disable the checkbox as follows:

```
$('#checkbox').attr("disabled",true);
```

and if you are not using the database driven code then you can use it at client side javascript code as follows:

```
$('#checkbox').on('change',function(){
 $(this).attr("disabled",true);
});
```

Comment: ya,my code is database driven, so where should i add this code to?should i add to the html file or the php file?

Comment: If you know how to user AJAX request from html code and call a PHP code and then return some value from the PHP code and in you html page (javascript section) disable your checkbox.

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar with AJAX..Normally i just use html and php.

Comment: Ok I hope you are familiar with jquery. I am adding a new answer with the full code please interpret the code and implment thanx